# How can I add a background to the top of a container that already has a gradient background?

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients

So, I have a container that has a gradient background but I want to add another different colored gradient background to some text at the top of my container. Here is an example of what I am talking about:
[image]

Basically what I want to do is add that dark grey background to the top of my container but also keep the gradient background below it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you draw a more specific exaple? From this picture I still know nothing.

Comment: Could you show us the markup you are using or are you free to make it whatever you need it to be?

Answer (score 1):

It depends which direction the gradients should go. If both are from top to bottom, you can simply write it as ONE gradient in the same background rule, using the same pixel or percentage value for the two different colors where you want to have the border between the two gradients (here 20%):

```css
.x {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6df 0%, #0d3 20%, #ffd 20%, #d90 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>

  <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate
    eleifend tellus.</p>

  <p>Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
    Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi.</p>

  <p>Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus.
    Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit
    cursus nunc,</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `div`, set the gradient for most of the background, make a child `div`, and set a new background color for it. Here is an example:

```css
#parent {background: black;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
#child {background: grey; width: 100px; height: 20px;}
* {color: white;} /*so you can see text*/
```

```html
<div id="parent"><div id="child">Special Text</div>Other gradient</div>
```

Hope it helped!